Why is conditional type not distributing over a union in TypeScript?
Body:
I’m encountering an issue with TypeScript's conditional types. I expected the conditional type to distribute over a union, but the result I’m seeing doesn't match my expectations.
Here’s a simplified version of my code:
type U6 = 'a' | 'b';
type Trans6<T> = T extends T ? T : never;
type PatX6<U> = Trans6<U> extends string ? [U] : never;
type T66 = PatX6<U6 | 'c'>; // Expected: [U6] | ['c'], but got: [U6 | "c"]

Could someone explain why the distribution isn't occurring here, and how TypeScript is evaluating this type? Additionally, is there a way to achieve the behavior I’m expecting?
Thank you!
I expected T66 to be a union of tuples, i.e., [U6] | ['c'], because I thought the conditional type should distribute over the union U6 | 'c'. However, TypeScript instead evaluates T66 as a single tuple containing the union type: [U6 | "c"].

Trans6<U> is not a naked type parameter, so Trans6<U> extends string ? [U] : never does not distribute over U.  See answer below and linked q/a above
